# Why small TCP connections succeeds, but big ones fails?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, tcp

Sometimes from Linux system I see the following weird behaviour:

I able to ping things and sometimes use some services, but networking is very bad.

For example, now I routed connection through my laptop (`-j MASQUERADE`) and observing the following thing: If I do little TCP connection (server sends few data to me), it proceeds:

```
# nc 86.57.151.3 80
GET /404
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

/proc/net/ip_conntrack has `tcp      6 431998 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.99.9 dst=86.57.151.3 sport=49104 dport=80 src=86.57.151.3 dst=93.125.21.218 sport=
80 dport=49104 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2` before I typed "GET /404".

But when I do big connection:

```
root@localhost:~# nc 86.57.151.3 80
GET /
```

It stalls. Before I enter "GET /" it shows ESTABLISHED ASSURED, as usual, but after I press Return it goes to `tcp      6 0 CLOSE_WAIT src=192.168.99.9 dst=86.57.151.3 sport=56991 dport=80 src=86.57.151.3 dst=93.125.21.218 sport=80 dpo
rt=56991 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2`. No packet with is received.  When I finally press Ctrl+C, it sends FIN to server, and Wireshard complains that server's FIN is "Out-of-order". Like if the reply packed dropped somewhere.

When I do the same `nc 86.57.151.3 80`/`GET /` from router, it works.

How to debug what is wrong?

Comment: What is your latency?

Comment: 10  ftp.mgts.by (86.57.151.3)  29.143 ms  29.363 ms  32.788 ms

Comment: MTUs: client system: `wlan0 MTU:1500`; router: `wifi0: MTU:1500; ppp4: MTU:1492`; One further router: all MTU's are 1500.

Comment: Strange: after setting all above mentioned MTUs to 1492 it seems started working. Why does MTU matter? Should it fragment things when needed?

Comment: @Vi: It *should*. However, some netadmins foolishly block all ICMP packets for "security" reasons, which means ICMP "Fragmentation Needed" errors get blocked too, and the sender *doesn't know* the fragmentation is needed. See [Path MTU Discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) and [Filtering ICMP](http://www.znep.com/~marcs/mtu/).

Comment: Looks like this is the answer. `traceroute 86.57.151.3 1500` shows dropped packets after certain router. Can you repost as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem with MTU and filtered ICMP messages somewhere.

Workaround is setting MTU on the client device or using TCP MSS clamping on router:

```
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -o ppp4 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```